# Python : How to choose modules that can be import from a package?

Tags: python, import, package

I have four packages in my program, among them i would like one and only one,  to be accessible from the outside, by a user of my program. Brievly, my programm, should be like a black box with only one entry(one of the package).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. But prefixing the "implementation" modules with a single underscore will act as an indicator that they should not be used directly.

Comment: Ok thanks, but how does modules like pygame etc.. make to hide their implementation..

Comment: They don't. Instead, they follow the convention I have described.